# ELASTICSEARCH - Count unique value with a condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like a query which it returns the number of times a field is repeated, according to the unique value of another field
I have this json:

```
          "name" : james,
          "city" : "chicago" <----------- same
        },
        {
          "name" : james,
          "city" : "san francisco"
        },
        {
          "name" : james,
          "city" : "chicago" <-----------same
        },
         {
          "name" : Mike,
          "city" : "chicago"
        },
         {
          "name" : Mike,
          "city" : "texas"<-----------same
        },
         {
          "name" : Mike,
          "city" : "texas"<-----------same
        },
         {
          "name" : Peter,
          "city" : "chicago"
        },
```

I want to make a query where I count based on the unique value of two fields.
For example, james is equal to 2, because there are two equal fields (name: james, city, chicago) and a different field (name: james, city: san francisco)
The output would then be the following:

```
  {
    "key" : "james",
    "doc_count" : 2
  },
  {
    "key" : "Mike",
    "doc_count" : 2
  },
  {
    "key" : "Peter",
    "doc_count" : 1
  },
```

It is possible to do a single value count of two fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a two level terms aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "citys_by_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "city.keyword",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will looks like this:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "names" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "james",
          "doc_count" : 15,
          "citys_by_name" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "chicago",
                "doc_count" : 14
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Peter",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "citys_by_name" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "chicago",
                "doc_count" : 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "mike",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "citys_by_name" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Or you can concatenate fields:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "return doc['name.keyword'].value + ' ' + doc['city.keyword'].value",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will looks lie this:

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "names" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "james chicago",
          "doc_count" : 14
        },
        {
          "key" : "Peter chicago",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If you want more stats on buckets, use the stats_buckets aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "return doc['name.keyword'].value + ' ' + doc['city.keyword'].value",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    },
   "names_stats":{
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path":"names._count"
      }
    }
    }
  }
```

Will result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "names" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "james PARIS",
          "doc_count" : 15
        },
        {
          "key" : "james chicago",
          "doc_count" : 13
        },
        {
          "key" : "samuel PARIS",
          "doc_count" : 11
        },
        {
          "key" : "fred PARIS",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    },
    "names_stats" : {
      "count" : 4,
      "min" : 2.0,
      "max" : 15.0,
      "avg" : 10.25,
      "sum" : 41.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: It would be possible to get number of keys of the in a buckets?
For example, in the last response with key: james chicago, key: Peter chicago;
number of key in buckets == 2.

Comment: Use Stats_buckets. I'll update my answer. But be careful with performance of this query

Comment: did my answer helps you? if so, please don't forget upvote

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that solved the problem for me

```
GET test/_search?filter_path=aggregations.count
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "return doc['name.keyword'].value + ' ' + doc['city.keyword'].value",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    },
    "count":{
      "cardinality": {"script": "return doc['name.keyword'].value + ' ' + doc['city.keyword'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
      "count" : {
        "value" : 2
    }
  }
}
```